# React Datagrid Individual Icon Update

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Working on an SFTP fileuploader. Small app sends uploads/downloads files to and from S3 and am using MUI DATAGRID.

Functionality is ok - I click download/upload and it download/upload the file from the row i clicked, however, my logic for replacing the download icon with a spinner icon affects all rows opposed to the one row i clicked. I believe i've set up React callback/usememo properly but still no luck. I feel i'm missing something small from my components.

Can anyone see something i'm missing here that would result in only the icon from the row i clicked changing?

The Component for the table containing the files.

```
import { FileDownload } from "@mui/icons-material";
import { CssBaseline, IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

import type { FileDetailsType, ListFilesProps } from "../../Types/Types";
import { downloadFile } from "../../api/fileAPI";
import Spinner from "../../utils/Spinner/Spinner";
import {
    errorToastOptions,
    successToastOptions
} from "../../utils/Toast/ToastOptions";

const ListFiles = ({ files }: ListFilesProps) => {
    const [fileDownloading, setFileDownloading] = useState(false);
    const [rows, setRows] = useState([]);


    useEffect(() => {
        setRows(
            files?.map((file) => {
                return {
                    name: file.name,
                    lastAccessedTime: file.lastAccessedTime,
                    lastModifiedTime: file.lastModifiedTime
                };
            })
        );
    }, [files]);

    const handleFileDownload = React.useCallback(
        async (fileData: FileDetailsType) => {
            try {
                setFileDownloading(true);
                const response = await downloadFile(fileData);
                if (response) {
                    const blob = new Blob([
                        response.data as unknown as BlobPart
                    ]);
                    const downloadURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    const tempLink = document.createElement("a");
                    tempLink.href = downloadURL;
                    tempLink.download = fileData?.name;
                    tempLink.click();
                    toast.success(
                        "File Download Successfully",
                        successToastOptions
                    );
                    setFileDownloading(false);
                } else {
                    toast.error("File Download Failed", errorToastOptions);
                    setFileDownloading(false);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                toast.error("File Download Failed", errorToastOptions);
                setFileDownloading(false);
            }
        },
        []
    );

    const renderRowBtn = useCallback(
        (params) => {
            return (
                <IconButton onClick={() => handleFileDownload(params.row)}>
                    {fileDownloading ? <Spinner /> : <FileDownload />}
                </IconButton>
            );
        },
        []
    );

    const columns = React.useMemo(
        () => [
            { field: "name", headerName: "Name", flex: 2 },
            { field: "lastAccessedTime", headerName: "Last Accessed", flex: 1 },
            { field: "lastModifiedTime", headerName: "Last Modified", flex: 1 },
            {
                field: "type",
                headerName: "",
                flex: 1,
                renderCell: renderRowBtn
            }
        ],
        []
    );

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />
            <div style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                <DataGrid
                    columns={columns}
                    rows={rows}
                    getRowId={(row) => row.name}
                />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default ListFiles;
```

The only other component here contains our axios calls.

```
import axios from "axios";

import type { FileDetailsType } from "../Types/Types";

export const checkIsConnected = async () => {
    return await axios.get(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/isconnected`);
};

export const listFiles = async () => {
    return await axios.get(
        `${process.env.API_URL}/api/listchildnodes?folderPath=/`
    );
};

export const downloadFile = async (fileData: FileDetailsType) => {
    return await axios.get(
        `${process.env.API_URL}/api/download?filePath=${fileData?.name}`,
        { responseType: "arraybuffer" }
    );
};

export const uploadFile = async (formData, xsrfToken) => {
    return await axios.post(`${process.env.API_URL}/api/upload`, formData, {
        headers: { "X-XSRF-TOKEN": xsrfToken }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependencies: fileDownloading, handleFileDownload

```
const renderRowBtn = useCallback(
    (params) => {
        return (
            <IconButton onClick={() => handleFileDownload(params.row)}>
                {fileDownloading ? <Spinner /> : <FileDownload />}
            </IconButton>
        );
    },
    [fileDownloading, handleFileDownload] 
);
```